# Windows 8 GetFileAsync method gives UnAuthorized error

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8.1

The below code an attempt to try and get get an Mp3 file from the MusicLibrary

It gives me,

```
A first chance exception of type 
'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
occurred in AccessingPictures.exe
```

This is my code:

```
public async void getFile()
{
    StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;

    try
    {
        sampleFile = await folder.GetFileAsync("Test1.mp3");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        // If file doesn't exist, indicate users to use scenario 1
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
    }
}

private void btnRead_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    getFile();
}
```

Wouldn't we able to access the media files?
I am able to do this using the file picker.
But it does not work while i try to access it directly.

Am i missing anything here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured the issue. It was because i hadn't enabled the capabilities in the Manifest file.

It works like a charm now.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve  Pictures from Camera Roll

```
 Void GetCameraPhotos()
      {
        using (var library = new MediaLibrary())
        {

            PictureAlbumCollection allAlbums = library.RootPictureAlbum.Albums;
            PictureAlbum cameraRoll = allAlbums.Where(album => album.Name == "Camera Roll").FirstOrDefault();
            var CameraRollPictures = cameraRoll.Pictures

        }
      }
```

Comment: MediaLibrary class is not available.

Comment: @golldy You need to add the reference, check this sample http://debugmode.net/2012/02/04/accessing-pictures-from-media-library-in-windows-phone/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the files unless it is in response to a user request.  i.e. the user must tap a button or something and that tap logic ends up calling your code that accesses the file.  If you want to get at the file afterwards, you'll need to copy it in the app's data folder.

Comment: Nope. Now i am stuck with accessing music files. I was able to access photos and videos....